# Removing space in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace, dataframe, strip

I am getting an error in my code because I tried to make a dataframe by calling an element from a csv. I have two columns I call from a file: CompanyName and QualityIssue. There are three types of Quality issues: Equipment Quality, User, and Neither. I run into problems trying to make a dataframe df.Equipment Quality, which obviously doesn't work because there is a space there. I want to take Equipment Quality from the original file and replace the space with an underscore.

input:

```
Top Calling Customers,         Equipment Quality,    User,    Neither,
Customer 3,                      2,           2,        0,
Customer 1,                      0,           2,        1,
Customer 2,                      0,           1,        0,
Customer 4,                      0,           1,        0,
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3

# Get the data.
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')   
# Group the data by calling CompanyName and QualityIssue columns.
byqualityissue = data.groupby(["CompanyName", "QualityIssue"]).size() 
# Make a pandas dataframe of the grouped data.
df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue) 
# Change the formatting of the data to match what I want SpiderPlot to read.
formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)[0]  
# Replace NaN values with zero.
formatted[np.isnan(formatted)] = 0 
includingtotals = pd.concat([formatted,pd.DataFrame(formatted.sum(axis=1), 
                             columns=['Total'])], axis=1)
sortedtotal = includingtotals.sort_index(by=['Total'], ascending=[False])
sortedtotal.to_csv('byqualityissue.csv')
```

This seems to be a frequently asked question and I tried lots of the solutions but they didn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

```
with open('byqualityissue.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    return [[x.strip() for x in row] for row in reader]
    sentence.replace(" ", "_")
```

And

```
sortedtotal['QualityIssue'] = sortedtotal['QualityIssue'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(' '))
```

And what I thought was the most promising from here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html:

```
formatted.columns = formatted.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_')
```

but I got this error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'str'

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You can do `df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).str.replace(' ','_')` as an aside why are you not just doing `df['Equipment Quality']` which will always work rather than trying to access the columns as an attribute which won't?

Comment: @EdChum Yes! Thanks for the aside, because I guess that should have been the real question rather than the work around. I wasn't sure about syntax, but that worked better.

Comment: While this is the older question, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476181/7758804) to [Removing space from columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41476150/7758804) is more appropriate for pandas, with significantly more views/votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
formatted.columns = [x.strip().replace(' ', '_') for x in formatted.columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, the following should work (test it out with `inplace=False` to see how it looks first if you want to be careful):

```
sortedtotal.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"), inplace=True)
```

And if you have white space surrounding the column names, like: "This example "

```
sortedtotal.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().replace(" ", "_"), inplace=True)
```

which strips leading/trailing whitespace, then converts internal spaces to "_".