# Remove or replace spaces in column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can spaces in dataframe column names be replaced with "_"?

```
['join_date' 'fiscal_quarter' 'fiscal_year' 'primary_channel'
 'secondary_channel' 'customer_count' 'new_members' 'revisit_next_day'
 'revisit_14_day' 'demand_1yr' 'revisit_next_day_rate'
 'revisit_14_day_rate' 'demand_1yr_per_new_member' u'ch_Ad Network'
 u'ch_Affiliate' u'ch_Branded SEM' u'ch_DSP' u'ch_Daily Email'
 u'ch_Daily Messaging' u'ch_Direct' u'ch_Direct Publisher' u'ch_Email'
 u'ch_Feeds' u'ch_Native' u'ch_Non-Branded SEM' u'ch_Organic Search'
 u'ch_Paid Social' u'ch_Site' u'ch_Special Email' u'ch_Television'
 u'ch_Trigger Email' u'ch_UNMAPPED' u'ch_Unpaid Social' u'quarter_Q2'
 u'quarter_Q3' u'quarter_Q4']
```

Answer (score 327):

- ***To remove white spaces***:

1. To remove white space *everywhere*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
```

2. To remove white space at *the beginning of string*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip()
```

3. To remove white space at *the end of string*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip()
```

4. To remove white space at *both ends*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

- ***To replace white spaces with other characters*** (underscore for instance):

5. To replace white space *everywhere*

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
```

6. To replace white space *at the beginning*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^ +', '_')
```

7. To replace white space *at the end*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' +$', '_')
```

8. To replace white space *at both ends*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^ +| +$', '_')
```

---

All above applies to a specific column as well, assume you have a column named `col`, then just do:

```
df[col] = df[col].str.strip()  # or .replace as above
```

---

Commands can be chained

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_')
```

Answer (score 2):

[Python string methods](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#string-methods) are extremely fast, and can be used in a list comprehension to fix column names:

```py
# replace white spaces by underscores
df.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df]

# strip leading white spaces
df.columns = [c.lstrip() for c in df]

# strip trailing white spaces
df.columns = [c.rstrip() for c in df]

# replace leading white spaces by underscores
df.columns = ['_' + c.lstrip() for c in df]
```

or `map` strip methods:

```py
# strip leading white spaces
df.columns = list(map(str.lstrip, df))
```

---

Since pandas' vectorized string methods ([`pandas.Index.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) and [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)) aren't optimized, using Python string methods in a comprehension is usually faster, especially if you need to chain them.

For example, for 100k column names, if you need to chain 3 methods together, Python string methods are 2-5 times faster than equivalent pandas methods.

```py
n = 100_000
df = pd.DataFrame([range(n)], columns=[f" {i} {j} " for i,j in zip(range(n), range(n, 0, -1))])

%timeit df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace('^ +', 'S', regex=True).str.replace(' +$', 'E', regex=True).str.replace(' ', '_'), axis=1)
# 331 ms ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.set_axis('S' + df.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_') + 'E', axis=1)
# 118 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.set_axis(['S' + c.strip().replace(' ', '_') + 'E' for c in df], axis=1)
# 68 ms ± 5.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```