# Pandas - Working with blank spaces

Tags: pandas, insert, newline, amazon-redshift

I have a Dataframe as below that has 3 columns namely id, name and feedback. One of the values for customer_input has a value as below

```
id,name,feedback
201,Robert,"response time is slow
"
```

I am having issues working inserting this data into a DB table due to the long text it hold in the feedback column. The entire text within quotes is value for one cell. How could I remove all the extra spaces between the word slow and the closing quotes (") in the next line Could anyone advice how I could work with this data.

I am working with Amazon Redshift table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple `str.replace`

```
df['feedback'] = df['feedback'].str.replace('\r','')

df['feedback'] = df['feedback'].str.replace('\n','')
print(df)
201  Robert  response time is slow
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove spaces everywhere, you could do it something like below in `Python pandas`.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
```

Refer following links for more details on various permutation combination.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace

[Removing space from dataframe columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476150/removing-space-from-dataframe-columns-in-pandas)