# How to dynamically append multiple data frames together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm loading data from a CSV into a data frame and then looping through the rows to do web queries.  All my code is shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Briefcase\\NY Times Dates\\exchanges.csv')
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    passin = 'https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange='+row["Symbol"]
    dfs = pd.read_html(passin)
    df = dfs[0]
    print(df)
```

My last step here is to append data frame #2 under data frame #1, and append data frame #3 under data frame #2, and so on and so on.  I Googled for a solution for this, and found several techniques to append #1 under #1, and that's it.

I'm not sure how to append data frame #n to data frame #n-1.  How can I do that?  I'm guessing it's an increment process, but I can't get it working here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
url = 'https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange='

res = pd.concat(pd.read_html(f'{url}{symbol}')[0] for symbol in df['Symbol'])
```

If you wish to ignore index when concatenating, use the argument `ignore_index=True`:

```
gen = (pd.read_html(f'{url}{symbol}')[0] for symbol in df['Symbol'])
res = pd.concat(gen, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hello.  I have followed you, and your comments, for the past 2+ years.  I up-voted so many of your comments!!  I know you know your stuff!!  No question about it!!  I followed your recommendation on this post, but I can't make this work.  I must have made a mistake.  I'm getting this error: KeyError: 'Symbol'  Thoughts???

Comment: @ryguy72, First check `print(df.columns)` and see if `'Symbol'` exists there, then check `print(df['Symbol'])` to see if it works. Your current solution implies there is a series labelled `'Symbol'`.

Comment: Well, when I do 'print(df['Symbol'])', I get the same result.  Here are the first 3 rows in 'exchanges.csv'
Name of Exchange Symbol
Australian Stock Exchange Ltd - Australia ASX
Euronext Paris - France PAR

Comment: By same result, I assume you mean `KeyError`. Then check `print(df.columns)`. You might have some unwanted whitespace (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476150/removing-space-from-dataframe-columns-in-pandas) to correct).

Comment: When I run the code I get this: KeyError: 'Symbol'.  I just updated my original post with the addition of your code.

Comment: @ryguy72, My solution doesn't involve an explicit `for` loop. Don't use `iterrows`.