# remove spaces in selected pandas columns at once

Tags: python, pandas

I think its simple question but i have problem with it.

How can I delete spaces in multiple columns at once in pandas dataframe?
example df:

```
A, B, C, D, E
 d,d ,s,s,a 
a ,a ,s,a ,r
```

I want to remove space in columns :`A,B,D,E`

normally i am using this method :

```
df['col']=df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

extending this one above i tried to use :

```
df[['A','B','D','E']]=df[['A','B','D','E']].apply(lambda x : x.strip())
```

but I am receiving an error:
`AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'"`

how to solve it?

additionally [Removing space from dataframe columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476150/removing-space-from-dataframe-columns-in-pandas) this one is not a duplicate, its only for columns names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), because working with `Series` (`columns`):

```
print (df)
    A   B  C   D   E
0   d  d   s   s  a 
1  a   a   s  a    r

df[['A','B','D','E']]=df[['A','B','D','E']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  d  d  s  s  a
1  a  a  s  a  r
```

Your solution should be possible with [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for element wise processing:

```
df[['A','B','D','E']]=df[['A','B','D','E']].applymap(lambda x : x.strip())
```

Or use if possible:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: there is no error anymore, but spaces has not been removed, also tried applymap, but spaces still there, any idea why?

Comment: @sygneto - hmm, for me working nice, maybe some data related problem, is possible check how data looks in list? `print (df['A'].tolist())` ?

Comment: thanks, i have found a problem in other column I had something wrong in my real data, it was like A_B, and in other rows A__B, and because of that this row with two '_' moved my other columns, thats why i thought i should delete space. anyway answer is ok for my question

Answer (score 1):

Other way is using the column type of your choice to do it at once like this:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns] = df[df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

where you can substitute 'object' type which represents string type to 'bool', 'int64', etc.